# Inserting image to SQL Server database , wrong filepath

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I'm trying to insert a `.JPG` into a SQL Server database using this query:

```
INSERT INTO Model (Id) 
    SELECT 1
    FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\Desktop\boat.jpg', Single_Blob) as ProductPicture
```

I'm getting this error:

> Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

I have checked the file path and it seems to be correct.

Comment: I guess it should be path on `SQL Server` server, not client local computer. Try using remote desktop and run from SSMS from there or use network share path.

Comment: Please check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19491812/2451726)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, "network share path" ? is there something i could add to the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 possibe issues:

- Permission. YOU are doing nothing - SQL Server is, so the SQL Server user needs permissions to access the file.
- Locality. Just because YOU find the file at C:\Desktop does not mean that your SQL Server does. The SQL is executed ON THE SERVER, not on your client.

Given that the path includes DESKTOP it is likely both.

Answer (score 1):

`OPENROWSET` with a drive letter is referring to the drive on the SQL Server machine, not your PC.

For details of how to use a network share (for example to access your PC), see this MSDN

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms175915.aspx#Anchor_3

And this for `OPENROWSET` in general

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx